# Python - 'And' operator not functioning properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, authentication

For some reason the `and` operator is not functioning properly within the `while` loop.

When I go to run the code it will exit the loop when either the password or username are matching and not both.

Any help would be great.

```
    root_password = "password123"
    root_username = "root"
    username = "default"
    password = "default"

    while username != root_username and password != root_password:
        username = input("Username: ")
        password = input("Password: ")
        if username != root_username and password != root_password:
        print("Wrong Credentials")


    print("Welcome")
```

Comment: Use `or` instead of `and`. Think it through.

Comment: @Aran-Fey is right, the problem is with the logic, not the operator.

Answer (score 2):

The and operator is exactly doing what it should, it stays in the loop as long as both are not matching.
What you want is continuing loop until both match, so you have to use the OR operator here

Answer (score 0):

This will result in True only when both, username and password don't match. In case the username is correct but password is wrong, False and True = False, and loop will end. What you need is to prompt "Wrong credentials" when either of them is wrong, using OR.

This is a common error while operating on negations or complements. Refer to De-Morgan Laws:

```
!(username == root_username and password==root_password)
```

is

```
username != root_username or password!=root_password
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to create a conditional which checks if both the username and password are matching and then put a `not` in front of that conditional, like this:

```py
not (username == root_username and password == root_password)
```

This just checks if the user doesn't have a matching username and password, or doesn't have the right credentials.

As Speeeddy has stated, using De-Morgan Laws, this conditional is the same as `username != root_username or password != root_password`, but this just makes the code easier to read and understand.

Here's the code with this change:

```py
root_password = "password123"
root_username = "root"
username = "default"
password = "default"

while not (username == root_username and password == root_password):
  username = input("Username: ")
  password = input("Password: ")
  if not (username == root_username and password == root_password):
    print("Wrong Credentials")

print("Welcome")
```